# How can I add a configuration file to Android Studio on Windows?

Tags: android, android-studio, configuration-files

Google has changed the documentation for generating registration ID and GCM in general. As always, the documentation is incomplete and include non-functional code, one of which is [adding a configuration file to the project](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client). I am stuck at this step:

```
move path-to-download/google-services.json app/
```

As it is an invalid Windows command. What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, don't copy and paste the line (it sounds like that the first time you read it). Then for Windows you don't need the dollar sign and use backslashes, not forward slashes.

Do not forget to write the path name in quotes. Else it will give "The syntax of the command is incorrect." exception.

```
 move "C:\yourdownload folder here\google-services.json" "app\"
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

Go to the Terminal in Android Studio (menu *View* → *Tool Windows* → *Terminal*) and issue:

```
move "path-to-download\google-services.json" app\
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the Android Studio terminal
2. Go to the *app/* folder
3. Type "move path-for-downloads/google-services.json"
4. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you can see the *google-services.json* file in your app folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the Terminal window in Android Studio (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> or menu *View* → *Tool* → *Windows* → *Terminal*).
- Then type "move file_path/google-services.json
  app/" without double quotes.

***Example***

```
move C:\Users\siva\Downloads\google-services.json app/
```

#### On Linux

Open Android Studio Terminal and type this:

Example:

```
scp '/home/developer/Desktop/google-services.json' 'app/'
```